# Using $_POST information only once

Tags: php

I have some information which gets passed from a form and needs to be used once and only once.  I can collect it nicely from $_POST but I'm not sure which is the "best" way to ensure that I can only use it once, i.e. I want to avoid the user pressing F5 repeatedly and accessing the function more than once.

My initial thought was to set a session variable and time the function out for a set period of time.  The problem with that is thay could have access to the function again after the set period has elapsed.

Better ideas welcomed!

Comment: What does the "function" actually do and how does it work?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: @DaveRandom, it really doesn't matter what the function is, and how it works. All that matters is that you need to break most browsers' repost-on-refresh behaviour

Comment: @PranavHosangadi oh yeh, lol, completely missed that one!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A redirect to another page would be sufficient to break most browser repost-on-refresh behaviour.  Setting a cookie on form submit (or a session variable, as you suggest) would also work quite nicely.  You could have the form submission page unset the session variable again, such that only a fresh access to the form would permit re-submitting the form.

Comment: Ah, dammit, just missed the bus!! :P

Comment: hmm its too late for the answer but i think the most easiest way is to use AJAX... :)

Answer (score 5):

This one's VERY easy to implement.

All you need to do is this:

have your form submit to a different page, which will only handle the post information, and not display ANYTHING

Then, send a LOCATION header to redirect the browser to a new page (which will be retreived by GET) This will break the browser's repost-on-refresh behaviour

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect to some other page, like doing

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

1) create a page with the form, eg myformpage.php

2) Make the action of the form myformpage_submit.php

3) in myformpage_submit.php do whatever it is you need to do with the posted info, like inserting into a database.

4) When finished, direct the browser to another page, eg nicework.php

This should dispose of them as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the user refreshing the page and accessing to the information,
You can use the token method in the form like this:

```
<?php 
if ( isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['token']) && ($_POST['token'] === $_SESSION['token']) )
{
    // do something here
}

$_SESSION['token'] = uniqid();

?>
```

And for the form

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?= $_SESSION['token'] ?>">
    <button name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```