# how to unset post array?

Tags: php, forms, post, form-submit

every time i am refreshing the page and i am getting the same value stored in the post array.
i want execution of echo statement only after submit and after refreshing no echo results..

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo "User name : <b> $name </b>";


}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: use unset($_POST['value']);

Comment: This post will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765144/unset-post-variables-after-form-submission

Comment: That is expected behaviour. If you refresh a POSTed form then it will do that.  However if you want data to show only once per submit you can store a session variable and run a check on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you submit a form and then refresh the resulting page, the browser will re-post the form (usually prompts first). That is why the POST data is always present.

An option would be to store a session variable and have it sent in the form, then check if it matches in the form processing code - to determine if it is a re-post or not.

Within the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="time" value="<?php echo $time; ?>" />
```

In the PHP:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['time']) && $_SESSION['time'] == $_POST['time'])
    {
        echo "User name : <b> $name </b>";
    }
}

$time = $_SESSION['time'] = time();
```

Another option is to redirect after processing the post data:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    ...
    ...

    header('Location: ' . basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
    exit();
}
```

Comment: after refreshing it is giving error "Notice: Undefined index: time"

Comment: it is not even printing name after using header

Comment: I've added an `isset()` to prevent the `Notice`. The session option is better than the redirect because you can't print anything before a redirect.

Answer (score 2):

From just a form, you won't be able to check if it was a refresh, or a first submit, regardless of using GET or POST method.

To ensure a single message, you need to:

a. redirect the user to somewhere else after you processed the request.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  // process data
  header("Location: new-url");
}
```

And display the message on the other URL.

b. set a cookie / session variable, which tells you the form was already processed.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !isset($_SESSION['form_processed'])) {
  $_SESSION['form_processed'] = true;
}
```

This second approach will kill your form until the user closes the browser, so you should do something more complex - like storing another hidden field in the form, and storing that in the session.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain a state as to whether `$name` has already been displayed or not. The easiest way is probably to maintain that state in a browser cookie.

```
<?php
$nonce = $_COOKIE['nonce'];
$new_nonce = mt_rand();
setcookie('nonce', $new_nonce);
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['nonce'] == $nonce) 
{ 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo "User name : <b> $name </b>";
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="<?php echo $new_nonce ?>">
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>
```

## Problems

- you are polluting the user “session” with stale variable.
- this will break if your user opens several windows (or tabs) to the same page. To fix this you would have to change the `nonce` cookie into an array of nonces, and update it accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

if you want refresh page after submit use

```
<form method="get"
```

sure if your form hasn't a lot of data and also need to use $_GET instead of $_POST variable:)
correct way for you, but this logic is not good, need to refactor this script:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo "User name : <b> $name </b>";
unset($_POST['submit']);
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>
```