# A form submit button reacts to isset function but only once

Tags: php, forms

I have a form who uses the post method:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
```

And I have an input at the end of it to submit the information typed:

```
<input type="submit" name="okform" value="Submit"/>
```

Here is PHP code I tried to execute:

```
<?php

$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=pure', 'root', '');

if(isset($_POST['okform'])){
    echo "yo";
} 

?>
```

the "yo" string shows when I click on the submit button, but when I refresh my website page the string is still shown. The `$_POST['okform']` variable is set even after refreshing the webpage. Why? I don't understand.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't want it to be present but it is! That's the problem

Comment: When you refresh a page with posted info it usually asks you if you want to resend the info. Try typing in the url again and hitting enter (not hitting refresh)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253119/how-to-unset-post-array

Comment: When you refresh browser in same page, it will ask to resubmit the posted data??

Comment: Thanks joshnik ! it works :)

Comment: Just make sure once you refresh the page that you're sending a POST request and not a GET request, generraly a popup helps you to do that

Comment: [Also read this it's a useful note on this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36741823/3536236)