# PHP Tips: How can I avoid my "receipt-page" to load twice?

Tags: php, mysql, timer, payment

When the user finishes the registration and payment, the bank automatically calls my receipt page twice.
I have contacted the bank about this and they say that this is intended.

My problem is that on the receipt-page the user is inserted to the member database (mysql) and a confirmation-email is sent. Since the bank calls for this page twice, I get two users and two emails are sent.

Is there any way to put a timer or any script that avoids the actual mysql_query or the mail function to be used twice? I have run out of ideas.

Comment: Does the bank provide a transaction id or user id or something like that?

Comment: yeah they call my page with some POST vars, one of them is a reference number

Comment: Can you store the reference number and check to see if it's already been processed in that case?

Comment: actually this just gave me an idea. Before I do the mysql_query and mail I can check if there already is a row in the database with the transaction id.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unset post variables after form submission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765144/unset-post-variables-after-form-submission)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to create a session.

Try this pseudocode.

```
$_SESSION['bank'] = 0;

if <First Display Here>
$_SESSION['bank'] = 1;


if ($_SESSION['bank'] == 0)
send email here
else
whatever code you want here
```