# PHP Display result on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
 <form action="" method="post">
     <div id="wrapper">
         <p> 
             <label> Please Enter the JCID No </label> 
             <input type="text" name="txt_jcid_no" id="txt_jcid_no"/>
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" class="bg-primary"/>
         </p>
         <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th>Name</th>
                     <th>Position</th>
                     <th>Office</th>
                     <th style="display: none"></th>
                     <th style="display: none"> </th>
                     <th style="display: none"></th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <?php
             if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                 echo 'Hi';
                 echo '<tbody>';
                 echo '</tbody>'; 
             }
             ?> 
         </table>
         <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
     </div>
 </form>
```

Dear friends i want my php code to display the value on the same page , so what i do here is get `input(txt_jcid_no)` from the user and process the query and display the value in table format . But when i use `if isset()` function it displays the value while the page loads i.e before clicking the `submit` button but my requirement is the value should be displayed in table after clicking the submit button.

Comment: have you seen browser confirm box asking about post data during page load

Comment: The $_POST['submit'] will not be set until unless you post the form. Just refresh the page & have a check(Not the resubmitting the form).

Comment: Keep in mind that once you submit the form, refreshing the page will **resubmit the form**. If you want to start over, youll need to click in the address bar and press enter, to actually navigate to the page fresh

Comment: Use Ajax if the data processing needs to be done serverside (if you need to request a db for instance). Or just process your data clientside in js/jquery if it's only calculation (if no serverside hosted data is requested).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335828/how-to-delete-post-variable-upon-pressing-refresh-button-on-browser-with-php this may help you.

Answer (score 1):

It would really be best to do this with ajax. You can still have all your code in one page, and just have the ajax call a second copy of the page like so:

### [Working demo](http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/posttosamepage/withajax.php)

```
<?php
 // at the top of your file have your response logic
 if (isset($_POST['txt_jcid_no'])){
    echo '<tbody><tr><td colspan="6">I was echoed here because you submitted the form</td></tr></tbody>'; 
    exit; // dont load the rest of the page if this was hit, we just want the above to be returned
 }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <div id="wrapper">
  <p>
    <label> Please Enter the JCID No </label>
    <input type="text" name="txt_jcid_no" id="txt_jcid_no">
  </p>
</form>
<input type="button" value="Search" id="submit" class="bg-primary">
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="result">
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
</div>
<script>
$(function(){ 
    $('#submit').click(function(){
          var dataString = 'txt_jcid_no=' + $('#txt_jcid_no').val();;
                                 
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "withajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(result) {
              $('#result').html(result);
            },
            error: function() {
            }
         });
         
        
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

If you really want to do it by posting the form, this will work:

#### [Working demo](http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/posttosamepage/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <div id="wrapper">
  <p>
    <label> Please Enter the JCID No </label>
    <input type="text" name="txt_jcid_no" id="txt_jcid_no">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" class="bg-primary">
  </p>
</form>
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th style="display: none"></th>
      <th style="display: none"> </th>
      <th style="display: none"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
 {
 echo '<tbody><tr><td colspan="6">I was echoed here because you submitted the form</td></tr></tbody>'; 
 }
 ?>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go one of two ways.

The first would be to include some logic which would determine whether the form was submitted to itself like so:

```
<body>
    <?php if($receivedResult): ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <p> <label> Please Enter the JCID No </label>
            <input type="text" name="txt_jcid_no" id="txt_jcid_no">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" class="bg-primary">
        </p>
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th style="display: none"></th>
                    <th style="display: none"> </th>
                    <th style="display: none"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php else; ?>
        <h1>you submitted a result</h1>
        ...
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
</div>
</body>
</form>
```

or, you could set up an AJAX endpoint and have the form not perform a standard post and instead send and receive data from this AJAX endpoint and dynamically process the response in Javascript (this example uses jquery).

```
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <label> Please Enter the JCID No </label>
            <input type="text" name="txt_jcid_no" id="txt_jcid_no">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" class="bg-primary"> 
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        $('input[type=submit]').submit(function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();

            .ajax({
                url: 'some/end/point',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                    console.log( errorThrown );
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally once you submit the form and refreshing the page will resubmit the form. So you need to hit enter from address bar. 
You may put following code under `</thead>` tag. Either you don't want to go with Ajax or not include another page.

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
 {
     $con = mysql_connect('localhost','username','password') or die(mysql_error());;
     mysql_select_db('db',$con) or die(mysql_error());
     //process your query here
     //e.g. $sql = "selelct * FROM tablename WHERE columnname = ". $_POST['txt_jcid_no'];
     //fetch query as per your choice 
     //and print outpout here..

 echo '<tbody>';
 foreach($result as $_value){
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>". $_value['name'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>". $_value['position'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>". $_value['office'] . "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
 }
 echo '</tbody>'; 
 mysql_close();
 }
 ?>
```