# "Failed - Network error" on Chrome browser with a PHP generated PNG image

Tags: php, google-chrome, png, image-generation

I create an image with PHP and output it in the following way

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);
...
header('Content-type: image/png');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

If I right click on the image and select 'Save image as...' in Chrome browser I get a "Failed - Network error". It does not save the image to a file. If I do the same with FireFox, Safari, or IE it works fine.
I have tried to add the content disposition header like so:

```
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename=image.png');
```

This did not fix it. Chrome also shows the filename to be saved as a .php file, the name of the generating PHP file, not a .png extension as FireFox for example does. Anybody knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try sending the headers before doing anything else. Maybe there's a whitespace in the output?

Comment: I have tried putting headers at the very beginning. It didn't make any difference. The PNG image is perfectly fine displayed by the Chrome browser. Thus it knows it is a PNG image. Why it cannot download it as a file is a mystery. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achive? Calling a PHP script showing the image or providing a download? If you want to provide a download then you probably need to do a redirect and then send the Content-Disposition header.

Comment: I want that the image is displayed AND that right-clicking on it allows one to save the image file. The displaying part works fine. The saving part does not work on Google Chrome browser. I want to make it also work on Google Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to unload the POST variable, save data in a session and reload the page or basically implement PGR pattern, which prevents double POST submit and such.

For my website, where I generate html  tags for images inside a php loop and the website is protected by a simple form, it solved the issues that images could not be downloaded with "save as" function (chrome newest and Edge as well, others not tested)

My solution pattner is stolen here: [How to delete $_POST variable upon pressing 'Refresh' button on browser with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335828/how-to-delete-post-variable-upon-pressing-refresh-button-on-browser-with-php)

Comment: Accusing people of stealing things in your answer is not the wisest thing to do. Not what answers are for.